# Postgres UPDATE with data from another table - index only scan used for correlated subquery but not join

Tags: postgresql, update, postgresql-performance, postgresql-9.6

**Context**

I'm tuning a bulk `UPDATE` which selects from another (large) table. My intention is to provide a covering index to support an index only scan of the source table. I realise the source table must be vacuumed to update its visibility map.

My investigations so far suggest the optimiser elects to index only scan the source table when the `UPDATE` uses a correlated subquery, but appears to use a standard index scan when a join is used (`UPDATE...FROM`). I'm asking this question to understand why.

I provide a simplified example here to illustrate the differences.

I'm using Postgres 9.6.8, but get very similar plans for 10.11 and 11.6. I have reproduced the plans on a vanilla 9.6 Postgres installation in Docker using the [official image](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/0d0485cb02e526f5a240b7740b46c35404aaf13f/9.6/Dockerfile), and also on db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=0fbbcf4b4ba7dca30159ca225aceb477).

**Setup**

```
CREATE TABLE lookup (
    surrogate_key   BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    natural_key     TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    data            TEXT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO lookup
SELECT id, 'nk'||id, random()::text
FROM generate_series(1,400000) id;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX lookup_ix ON lookup(natural_key, surrogate_key);

VACUUM ANALYSE lookup;

CREATE TABLE target (
    target_id               BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    lookup_natural_key      TEXT NOT NULL,
    lookup_surrogate_key    BIGINT,
    data                    TEXT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO target (target_id, lookup_natural_key, data)
SELECT id+1000, 'nk'||id, random()::text
FROM generate_series(1,1000) id;

ANALYSE target;
```

**UPDATE using join**

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYSE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS)
UPDATE target
SET lookup_surrogate_key = surrogate_key
FROM lookup
WHERE lookup_natural_key = natural_key;
```

Standard index scan on `lookup_ix` - so heap blocks are read from `lookup` table:

```
Update on public.target  (cost=0.42..7109.00 rows=1000 width=54) (actual time=76.688..76.688 rows=0 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=8514 read=550 dirtied=16
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..7109.00 rows=1000 width=54) (actual time=0.050..62.493 rows=1000 loops=1)
        Output: target.target_id, target.lookup_natural_key, lookup.surrogate_key, target.data, target.ctid, lookup.ctid
        Buffers: shared hit=3479 read=535
        ->  Seq Scan on public.target  (cost=0.00..19.00 rows=1000 width=40) (actual time=0.013..7.691 rows=1000 loops=1)
              Output: target.target_id, target.lookup_natural_key, target.data, target.ctid
              Buffers: shared hit=9
        ->  Index Scan using lookup_ix on public.lookup  (cost=0.42..7.08 rows=1 width=22) (actual time=0.020..0.027 rows=1 loops=1000)
              Output: lookup.surrogate_key, lookup.ctid, lookup.natural_key
              Index Cond: (lookup.natural_key = target.lookup_natural_key)
              Buffers: shared hit=3470 read=535
Planning time: 0.431 ms
Execution time: 76.826 ms
```

**UPDATE using correlated subquery**

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYSE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS)
UPDATE target
SET lookup_surrogate_key = (
    SELECT surrogate_key
    FROM lookup
    WHERE lookup_natural_key = natural_key);
```

Index only scan on `lookup_ix` as intended:

```
Update on public.target  (cost=0.00..4459.00 rows=1000 width=47) (actual time=52.947..52.947 rows=0 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=8050 read=15 dirtied=16
  ->  Seq Scan on public.target  (cost=0.00..4459.00 rows=1000 width=47) (actual time=0.052..40.306 rows=1000 loops=1)
        Output: target.target_id, target.lookup_natural_key, (SubPlan 1), target.data, target.ctid
        Buffers: shared hit=3015
        SubPlan 1
          ->  Index Only Scan using lookup_ix on public.lookup  (cost=0.42..4.44 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.013..0.019 rows=1 loops=1000)
                Output: lookup.surrogate_key
                Index Cond: (lookup.natural_key = target.lookup_natural_key)
                Heap Fetches: 0
                Buffers: shared hit=3006
Planning time: 0.130 ms
Execution time: 52.987 ms
```

db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=0fbbcf4b4ba7dca30159ca225aceb477)

I understand that the queries are not logically identical (different behaviour when there a no/multiple rows in `lookup` for a given `natural_key`), but I'm surprised by the different usage of `lookup_ix`.

Can anyone explain why the join version *could not* use an index only scan please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An index only scan can only be used if all columns that the index scan returns are stored in the index.

Yours index `lookup_ix` contains only the columns `natural_key` and `surrogate_key`, but from the execution plan you can see:

```
->  Index Scan using lookup_ix on public.lookup
      Output: lookup.surrogate_key, lookup.ctid, lookup.natural_key
```

So the index scan fetches the `ctid` the physical address of the row. This is because we are going to perform an `UPDATE`; see this comment from `src\include/nodes/plannodes.h`:

```
 * When doing UPDATE, DELETE, or SELECT FOR UPDATE/SHARE, we have to uniquely
 * identify all the source rows, not only those from the target relations, so
 * that we can perform EvalPlanQual rechecking at need.  For plain tables we
 * can just fetch the TID, much as for a target relation; this case is
 * represented by ROW_MARK_REFERENCE.  Otherwise (for example for VALUES or
 * FUNCTION scans) we have to copy the whole row value.  ROW_MARK_COPY is
 * pretty inefficient, since most of the time we'll never need the data; but
 * fortunately the overhead is usually not performance-critical in practice.
 * By default we use ROW_MARK_COPY for foreign tables, but if the FDW has
 * a concept of rowid it can request to use ROW_MARK_REFERENCE instead.
 * (Again, this probably doesn't make sense if a physical remote fetch is
 * needed, but for FDWs that map to local storage it might be credible.)
```

(`EvalPlanQual` is PostgreSQL a jargon term/function name for fetching the latest version of a row that will be locked or modified.)

To ascertain that this is the case, try `EXPLAIN`ing the same query without the update, and you will see that the plan is the same, except the `ctid`s are not fetched, and it uses an index only scan.

---

Now there is one thing that is surprising to me:

Every (leaf) index entry **does** contain the `ctid` of the row it references, so I don't see a reason why that cannot be fetched with an index only scan. I [asked on the mailing list](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/b6a2860abd533fef12f6b713c109d29f3e3c2a15.camel%40cybertec.at), but it seems that changing this might not be trivial.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, particularly the reference to the source code. I had noticed the `ctid` in the plan, but assumed that was a necessary consequence of the visibility check on the tuples in the table. I will take your advice to ask on pgsql-hackers, I was reluctant to do that in the first instance because I assumed I had missed something obvious.

Comment: I see you asked the question on pgsql-hackers and it's not simple, so I'll just go with the correlated subquery. Thanks again.

Comment: HOT updates can change the `ctid` of a heap tuple without changing the index tuple. So while data in the index is current, the `ctid` may be outdated (point to a dead tuple). One would have to check the heap and follow any possible HOT chain. Doesn't that void any attempt at index-only scans on principal?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Yes, that must be the explanation.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Presumably it is still _in theory_ possible (but not necessarily practical) to determine that the source table for an update satisfies the usual visibility map check for an index only scan? The `ctid` is then not needed to check visibility of the heap tuple, regardless of any possible HOT chain. Otherwise I don't see how the subquery version of the update is able to use an index only scan?

Comment: Visibility, yes. But if the index scan needs to return the actual `ctid` of the tuple, that is not available outside the table.

Comment: @coder: Currently the visibility map can guarantee, per data page, that user values in indexes are current. The `ctid` is included in index tuples (has to be), but can still be outdated, as commented above. We'd need an extended visibility map (currently two bits per page) or a similar structure indicating any HOT chains per page to allow an extended index-only scan including the `ctid`. While that can pay in theory, the gain is certainly smaller than what we get from current VMs. And it would be a major project to implement it.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: Tracking that information *per table* with applicable indexes might be worthwhile, though? Many tables never use HOT updates for a variety of reasons. A single datum per table indicating "no HOT chains inside" might be simple and cheap enough? (Or am I missing other possible ways how index `ctid` can be outdated?)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter True. There might be hight contention on that datum though, and it would have to be persisted in a crash safe fashion, I think.